# MySQL Inner Join Update

Tags: php, sql, database, join, mysqli

I am trying to perform a relational update using an innjer join and can't seem to get the syntax correct.

The rows are as follows:

```
Catalogue.Category_ID
Catalogue.Visible

Categories.Category_ID
Categories.Category_Name
```

I am trying to update the value of the visible field when the category ID numbers match and correspond the the correct name.

```
UPDATE `Catalogue` 
SET `Visible` = '0' 
FROM `Catalogue` 
INNER JOIN `Categories` 
  ON Catalogue.Category_ID = Categories.Category_ID 
  AND Categories.Category_Name = 'Bases'
```

Apologies if it comes down to a stupid syntax mistake, i'm not the most experienced with relational databases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is the proper syntax:

```
UPDATE `Catalogue` 
INNER JOIN `Categories` 
  ON Catalogue.Category_ID = Categories.Category_ID 
  AND Categories.Category_Name = 'Bases'
SET `Visible` = '0'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `TSQL` syntax, here's for `MySQL`

```
UPDATE `Catalogue` 
       INNER JOIN `Categories`
           ON Catalogue.Category_ID = Categories.Category_ID

SET `Visible` = '0' 
WHERE Categories.Category_Name = 'Bases'
```

if you want to shorten the query, use `ALIAS`

```
UPDATE Catalogue a 
       INNER JOIN Categories b
           ON a.Category_ID = b.Category_ID

SET    Visible = '0' 
WHERE  b.Category_Name = 'Bases'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for:

```
UPDATE 'Catalogue' SET 'Visible' = '0' FROM 'Catalogue' INNER JOIN 'Categories' ON Catalogue.Category_ID = Categories.Category_ID
WHERE Categories.Category_NAME = 'Bases'
```